# Accessibility - UIPickerView as inputView

Tags: ios, uipickerview, voiceover

I'm using a `UIPickerView` as an inputView of `UITextField`.

```
self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

self.pickerView.dataSource = self.datasource;
self.pickerView.delegate = self.delegate;

//additional setups

self.textField.inputView = self.pickerView;
```

Everything works fine, but when i active voiceover and start to cycling through the itens, the voiceover start to make incorrect announcement.

I did some research and I found a repo on [github](https://github.com/saamerm/iOS-Accessibility-PickerView/) with someone that have the same problem, but i couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a workaround for this case. On the `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` method, i use `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` with `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification`, passing the item that was selected, forcing the voiceover to make the correct announcement.

Objective-C:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()){
        UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, self.items[row]);
    }
}
```

Swift:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning){
        UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.announcement, argument: self.items);
    }
}
```